# Calculate exit point from inside a circle using radius, position and direction

Tags: trigonometry

I want to calculate the exit point of a circle (in this case centered at 0,0) from any position within the circle in any direction.

So to clarify.

Circle A is centered at 0,0 and has a radius of 10.

Point B is at 4,4 and is "facing" right (90 degrees).

Assuming "forward" movement from B (i.e moving right), how do you calculate the exit point of the circle?

Comment: Please comment why if you downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Parametric representation 
of the point $P$ on the line 
through the point $B$
in direction $\vec{D}$ 
in terms of $t\in\mathbb{R}$
is
\begin{align} 
P&=B+t\cdot \vec{D}
,\\
\end{align}
which is in fact two equations

\begin{align} 
 P_x&=B_x+t\cdot {D_x}
 ,\\
 P_y&=B_y+t\cdot {D_y}
 .\\
\end{align}

If the point $B$ is internal,
this line intersects the circle boundary in two points, 
$C_1$ for some $t_1>0$, 
and $C_2$ for some $t_2<0$.

Coordinates of the point on a circle boundary 
can be represented parametrically as

\begin{align} 
C_x&=R\cos\phi
,\\
C_y&=R\sin\phi
,\quad \phi\in[0,2\pi]
.
\end{align}

Now we can get rid of $\phi$
and obtain a quadratic equation for $t$:

\begin{align}
R^2\cos^2\phi+
R^2\sin^2\phi
&=
(B_x+t\cdot {D_x})^2+(B_y+t\cdot {D_y})^2
,\\
(D_x^2+D_y^2)\,t^2+2\,(B_xD_x+B_yD_y)\,t-(R^2-(B_x^2+B_y^2)
&=0
,
\end{align}
which gives
\begin{align}
t_1&=\frac{-(B_x\,D_x+B_y\,D_y)+\sqrt{(B_x\,D_x+B_y\,D_y)^2+(D_x^2+D_y^2)\,(R^2-(B_x^2+B_y^2))}}
{D_x^2+D_y^2}
,\\
t_2&=\frac{-(B_x\,D_x+B_y\,D_y)-\sqrt{(B_x\,D_x+B_y\,D_y)^2+(D_x^2+D_y^2)\,(R^2-(B_x^2+B_y^2))}}
{D_x^2+D_y^2}
,\\
\end{align}
and the sought point $C_1$ is found as
\begin{align}
C_1&=B+t_1\,D
.
\end{align}

Comment: I want to understand, but some parts are confusing to me. What exactly does R cosϕ mean in this case? As in what does R and theta stand for (I have seen them mean really different things).
And in the last step, the function for getting t1 and t2 looks identical, shouldn't they differ somehow?

Comment: @webejaxx: It's a standard parametric form of [the equation of the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle)
which express the $x,y$ coordinates of the point in terms of the parameter $\phi$.
In this case a nice thing is that we don't really need to worry about $\phi$,
since we eliminate it anyway. And yes, $t_1$ and $t_2$ are different,
they are the two roots of the quadratic equation above, which in fact,
also works when the point $B$ is not internal. 
Just when it is internal, there are always two real roots,
otherwise there could be two, one or no real roots.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work, but I can't turn this into working code (for a game I am making). I get that a point on the boundry is worked out with `x = radius * Cos(angle* PI / 180)) + point.X` and `y = radius * Sin(angle* PI / 180)) + point.Y`. I don't understand the next steps well enough to write a function for it. Do you know how to help with that?

Comment: @webejaxx: You have the radius $R$,
the point $B=(B_x,B_y)$ 
and the direction $D=(D_x,D_y)$,
the formula to get $t_1$.
The point $C_1=B+t_1\cdot D$.
That's all.

Comment: Ohh, I get it now! Thank you, it worked perfectly.